# I get a 401 error when I try to access an organization in which I'm the owner

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Here's the message I get:

> Your account, [my email] is not authorized to view this page. Make
>   sure the URL is correct and your account has access. View a list of
>   your organizations here. You may request access by contacting the
>   admin.

[List of my organizations (I'm trying to access the first one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pohBG.png)

It also does not load this organization info in this screen.

This happened right after some changes in the Active Directory, when editing an email's user.

Also, no other user that belongs in this organization can access it (401 as well).

Does anyone know what's happening and how can I get access to it again?

Comment: Which change do you do on AAD? Since your org has backed AAD, so if you change any configuration of AAD, it will affect your access on org.

Comment: Could you please check your token on [Jwt](https://jwt.io/) if it is contain all required permission. It might happened after some change on azure portal regarding permission  modification. So I would suggest you to check the token first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the access permissions for this organization, if the organization is denied access for external access. Check the network permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.
But in my case, no changes in the AD. After linking Azure Devops Organization with Azure AD, we have lost the access.
There are 2 users in the organization, one of them is the owner, and the other one (magically became) a Stakeholder. The owner can't login to the organization (401 error), and the other user can't see the git repo because it is the stake holder (supposed to be Basic).
I did clear up cache, used different browsers, no luck.

Basically, as a result, I have lost access to the code repository.